# Почему не отрабатывает событие Edit?

Tags: google-apps-script

Пишу скрипт и столкнулся с такой проблемой, что событие `Edit` не возникает в при копировании в ячейку значения с помощью `[ctrl]+[v]`. Оно возникает только в случае, когда проваливаешься в ячейку двойным кликом и меняешь значение.

Подскажите пожалуйста какой выход? Заменять на `Change` не хочу, ибо там нет полезных свойств события `Edit` :(

Событие происходит в Таблицах Гугл. Да вот даже элементарный вывод алерта при срабатывании события `Edit` не сработает, если вставить данные методом копирования в ячейку - событие `Edit` просто не возникает. Оно возникает лишь во всех тех случая, когда проваливаешься в ячейку и меняешь данные.

```js
function functionKey(e) {
    var firstvalue = e.oldValue; //Начальное значение ячейки
    var finiteValue = e.value; // Конечное значение ячейки

    var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi(); // get ui for alert
    ui.alert(finiteValue); // вывод значения в окне alert

}

function createSpreadsheetOnEditTrigger() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    ScriptApp.newTrigger("functionKey")
        .forSpreadsheet(ss)
        .onEdit()
        .create();
}
```

Comment: Покажите кодом, что вы пытаетесь сделать и как

Comment: `onEdit` это кто? `onChange` - кто? Какая ячейка? Ничего не понятно. Нормально сформулируйте проблему.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Добавил код, посмотрите пожалуйста

Answer (score 0):

Это довольно интересный эффект.

Попробуйте не проверять `oldValue`, т.к. это свойство доступно только при редактировании *одной* ячейки.

> Cell value prior to the edit, if any. Only available if the edited range is a single cell. Will be undefined if the cell had no previous content.
>
> [Справка](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#edit)

Если не ошибаюсь, работа с буфером не относится к этому варианту. Поэтому всегда делайте

```js
const finiteValue = e.range.getValue();
```

Про предыдущее значение лучше забыть или использовать другой подход для хранения таких данных, например, обычное зеркалирование.

Comment: Спасибо большое! Работает так. Но  у меня 1 ячейка редактируется, а не диапазон. Но как мне теперь узнать старое значение? Мне нужно работать с oldValue и Value.

Comment: Этого в вопросе не было. Лучше всего задать еще один, а этот отметить как решение. Попробуйте хранить значение в заметках в ячейке. Не очень удобно, но иногда помогает.

Comment: А как его отметить решенным? У меня меньше 15 баллов репутации

Comment: Пример, что работает https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Oz11afzCvtNQPM6ampYR8B5C5K5JVYjNLTiQwpLn7Dw/edit#gid=2062669036

Comment: Да это работает, но моя проблема не решена полностью. Как теперь получить oldValue при копировании данных в ячейку?(